# Why does <p> element jump out of div and appear in next line below?

Tags: html, css

element is "jumping" out of its div and appearing one line below, outside the div. The element is floated right. There are two div elements, one holding a logo and business address, the next one down holding a drop-down menu and welcome statement. The drop-down menu is floated left. I did not include the html for the menu. This was not happening until today, but I do not know what I changed to cause this. I have not changed anything with the menu. Thanks for help. Happy New Year!

```
 <div id="head_1">
    <img src="images/Logos/Acts4_Logo.png"/>
   <p> P.O. Box 4524 </br>
       Waterville </br>
       </br>
       (444) 444 - 4444 </br>
        www.Acts.org 
   <p>
 </div>

 <!-- menu and statement -->
 <div id="head_2">
   <p>Keeping Families Warm in Winter</p>

 #contain {  /* wrapper for all content*/
    margin-right: 17%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0px 10px 1px 10px;
 }

#content {  /* all text and photos */
   margin-top: 20px;
   background-color: white;
}

#head_1 p {     /* Acts address */
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 11pt;
}


#head_2 p {  /* keep fams warm */
  float: right;
  font-family: "cursive standard";
  font-size: 26pt;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is but you do have some issues with your html:

1. `<div id="head_2">` is not closed, but I'm going to guess that was just left out in your example and not in your actual code.
2. You have an open `<p>` instead of a close
3. the `<br/>` tags are closed wrong (you have `</br>`:

   ```
   <div id="head_1">
     <img src="images/Logos/Acts4_Logo.png"/>
     <p> P.O. Box 4524 </br> <---------------------#3 all of these should be <br/>
     Waterville </br>
     </br>
     (444) 444 - 4444 </br>
     www.Acts.org 
     <p> <--------------#2 should be </p>
   </div>

   <!-- menu and statement -->
   <div id="head_2">
     <p>Keeping Families Warm in Winter</p>
   </div> <----- #1 Missing
   ```

Also you need to clear floats which you may or may not be doing. It appears that `#contain` is your wrapper so you can add `overflow: hidden` to that if it is in fact a parent to `#head_1` and `#head_2`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xsb7tkwg/)

Comment: I fixed the mistakes you pointed out. All tags are closed and formatted properly. I have not learned the concept of "clear floats" yet.